# The dreaded "Not a valid JPG" error

Tags: images, jpg, error

I've got a bunch of files where I'm getting this error.  Also:

```
Not a valid TIF 
Not a valid PNG 
etc...
```

These files may have been saved directly from a camera (Panasonic ZS-1) or edited at one point in either Photoshop CS5 or Paint Shop Pro 5.  At any given point, they were valid files which opened fine using one of those applications, and all of a sudden they appear to be corrupted and no longer open.

Is there any way to fix these files?

Comment: How are we expected to be able to fix this without access to the files?

Comment: Well, this is a graphics stack, so I thought maybe graphics professionals had seen this error often and there might be some general trick or tidbit of info used.

Comment: You could utilize a scripting option like ImageMagick to save the file into another format or the same format to possibly clear whatever the issue is.

Comment: Also, have you looked at the image metadata?  Some scripting engines will allow you to parse the metadata.  If this is wrong that could be what is throwing the error.

Comment: Furthermore, you do not disclose how the images were created.  If you created the images in another format and just changed the file type that would throw an error in some applications.

Comment: If you can make an [edit] to provide at least some of the stuff I mentioned above then your question would go into the reopen Q to possibly be able to provide a solution.  Myself included would be able to provide an answer with options.

Answer (score 1):

Often such files may open in *other* applications.

For example, a JPG may error with Photoshop here.... but opens fine in GraphicsConverter... so it just need to be opened and re-saved from the *other* application.

Barring that.. the file is hosed... you can't generally "fix" the file.

Comment: The only "fix" I ever saw was opening them in IrfanView where the software showed me the error and offered to fix it.